# How do I use the Tkinter colorchooser value after the window is destroyed?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, colors

I'm trying to choose a color and after the window is closed, use that color to display a colored circle in OpenCV. But I'm not able to access those values after the Tkinter window is collapsed.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import colorchooser

global rgb
global hex    
root = Tk()

def close():
    root.destroy()

def getColor():
    (rgb, hex)= colorchooser.askcolor()
    print(rgb, hex) #prints the values

root.geometry("300x300")
button = Button(root, text="Choose a color", command=getColor)
button.pack()
button = Button(root, text="Quit and continue", command=close)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
print(rgb, hex) #shows an error saying rgb not defined
```

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of issues with your code.

1. > *shows an error saying rgb not defined*

   Well you haven't defined `rgb` and `hex` anywhere in the code and what you think these are doing **`global rgb` and `global hex`**. *I recommend having a look at [global](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword) keyword.*
2. *Don't use `hex` as a variable because `hex` is a [python keyword](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/keywords-identifier).* Use something else like `Hex` or `hexcode`.
3. *The variables of `getColor()` are removed from the memory when the function end.* To save those, either return those values or save it in global variables or in `list`, `tuple`, `dict`. I personally use a dictionary or a list for such situations.

   ```py
   color = {}

   def getColor():
       color['rgb'], color['hex'] = colorchooser.askcolor()
       print(color['rgb'], color['hex']) # prints the values
   ```

---

If getting color is all you need and does not require a Tkinter window then you make a function just to return color without having a Tkinter window.

```py
def getColor():
    """Choose color.
    Returns tuple of RBG and HEX."""
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor
    win = None
    if not tk._default_root:
        win = tk.Tk()
        win.wm_withdraw()
    color = askcolor()
    if win is not None: 
        win.destroy()
    return color

rgb, hexcode = getColor()
print(rgb, hexcode)
```

Comment: Works fine! Thank you so much! 
Can you explain what you did in this part?
if not tk._default_root:
        win = tk.Tk()
        win.wm_withdraw()

Comment: @AmritaNair: `tk._default_root` is to check if there is any active Tkinter window already, if not then `win = tk.Tk()` this creates one as it is required to have an active window to use `askcolor()` and [`win.wm_withdraw()`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.withdraw-method) is used to withdraw a window from the screen means to hide it in the taskbar.